# Selection for the same dates (if-else?)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have such values ​​in the table

```
 id_task  id_status           dt_upd_status       rank
     100         10        2021-04-05 10:59:11      2   
     100         20        2021-04-05 10:59:11      1
     101         10        2021-04-06 12:59:06      2
     101         20        2021-04-06 12:59:06      1
     102         10        2021-04-07 15:30:06      2
     102         20        2021-04-07 16:12:33      1
     103         10        2021-04-07 15:12:26      1
```

I have a query in which I use rank

```
rank() over (partition by id_task order by ftsh.dt_upd_status desc) as rnk
```

but only output a value with a rank of 1

```
where q.rnk = 1
```

Rank goes in descending order, I only need the maximum task time, but if the task has the same time, then the status is incorrect.

At the exit, I want to get this

```
   id_task  id_status           dt_upd_status     rank
        
     100         20        2021-04-05 10:59:11      1
     101         20        2021-04-06 12:59:06      1
     102         20        2021-04-07 16:12:33      1
     103         10        2021-04-07 15:12:26      1
```

If the task has the same time, then you need to bat only with the status 20

Comment: Didn't someone ask a very similar question here yesterday? Scroll down and see if you can find it, and its answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't found anything similar yet. Only links to postgres documentation, but it didn't work out for me with case

Comment: [`distinct on (...)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

Comment: @Abelisto No, this will not work, since there may be different tasks with the same time, and this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only one row, and always one row, then you are advised to use `row_number()` instead of `rank()` because the latter can assign multiple rows the same rank, but row_number cannot.

If I understand your question correctly then what you need is a "tie breaker" to control which single row is chosen if there is a tie on the date like this:

```
row_number() over (partition by id_task 
               order by ftsh.dt_upd_status desc, status DESC ) as rn
```

If there are more then 10 or 20 as values in the Status column then you could use a case expression as part of the ordering like this:

```
row_number() over (partition by id_task 
      order by ftsh.dt_upd_status desc, case when status = 20 then 0 else 1 end ) as rn
```

Comment: I'm trying now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not want duplicates (i.e. `row_number()` rather than `rank()`, then I would recommend `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (ftsh.id_task) ftsh.*
from ftsh
order by ftsh.id_task, ftsh.dt_upd_status desc, ftsh.status desc;
```

This usually has better performance, when compared to window functions.

If you specifically want "20" first, then you can use:

```
order by ftsh.id_task, ftsh.dt_upd_status desc, (ftsh.status = 20) desc;
```